# Java validating input values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, string-utils

```
 private String createSearchFieldContent(OverrideableStringValue title,
                                         OverrideableContactValue owner) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getValue(title));

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getValue(owner).getFamilyName())) {
        builder.append(" ").append(getValue(owner).getFamilyName());
    }

    String searchTerm = StringUtils.replaceAll(builder.toString(), "\n", " ");

    return unaccent(searchTerm);
}
```

There are four values, which I get from an API and they are not possible as `familyName`. Is there a way to don't add them to the `searchTerm`? I'm thinking about something like `StringUtils.contain()` and then there the invalid values...

Thanks for help!

Comment: create exception? what exception? in which cases? is it throwing an exception? are you trying to throw one yourself?µ

Comment: @Stultuske exception would be the best way but I'm not pretty sure how I can do that correctly

Comment: do what correctly, you're still not being clear about what it is you're trying to do

Comment: @Stultuske I got some values which are not allowed and I know these values. I like to add an exception for those four values - if I get these values, it shouldn't add them to the string

Answer (score 1):

If you know what 4 values from API should not be appended then declare as constants.
Now there are 2 ways from here :
1) Either compare all those 4 constants with family name or
2) Add them in hashset then use contains check with family name